# Adding 'aria-labels' to anchor links in WordPress navigation menu

Tags: wordpress, accessibility, wai-aria

I am needing to add custom aria-labels to each of the menu (and sub-menu) items in my WordPress website. It is running a custom theme.

I would like the aria-labels to include the page title like this:

aria-label="Page Title"

So in the end each LI within the navigation menu structure would look something like this:

```
<li id="id_name" class="class_names"><a href="http://linktothepage.com/page" aria-label="TITLE OF MY PAGE">TITLE OF MY PAGE</a></li>
```

What is the most efficient way to do this?
A filter? 
Something else?

Comment: Why do you want to add `aria-labels`? In the example you provide, it merely repeats what a screen reader would announce without them (the linked text).

Answer (score 4):

This question is pretty old, but I found it while searching for the answer myself, and I thought I'd answer in case someone else got here.

In my case, I wanted to add aria-labels to menu items which had children, because when testing my menu w/ VoiceOver, I noticed that it needed to be clearer that the link would open the menu below.

There is a filter in the `Walker_Nav_Menu` class which addresses a menu item's attributes, `nav_menu_link_attributes`. (This is in wp-includes/class-walker-nav-menu.php) You can use that to edit the array of attributes to be added to the link.

My goal was to simply add the word "Menu" at the end of the name of the link if the link (a) was just "#" and (b) had children items. This worked for me, YMMV:

```
/* @see jcdesign_label_menu_items() */
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'jcdesign_label_menu_items', 10, 4 );

/**
 * Filter nav menu items
 *
 * @param array $atts {
 *     The HTML attributes applied to the menu item's `<a>` element, empty strings are ignored.
 *
 *     @type string $title        Title attribute.
 *     @type string $target       Target attribute.
 *     @type string $rel          The rel attribute.
 *     @type string $href         The href attribute.
 *     @type string $aria_current The aria-current attribute.
 * }
 * @param WP_Post  $item  The current menu item.
 * @param stdClass $args  An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
 * @param int      $depth Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
 *
 * @see Walker_Nav_Menu
 *
 * @return array
 */
function jcdesign_label_menu_items( $atts, $item, $args, $depth ) {
    
    $empty_href   = ( ! isset( $atts[ 'href' ] ) || $atts[ 'href' ] === '#' || $atts[ 'href' ] === '' );
    $has_children = ( is_array( $item->classes ) && in_array( 'menu-item-has-children', $item->classes ) );
    
    // If href is essentially empty, and the item has children,
    // add an aria label noting that this is a menu
    if ( $empty_href && $has_children ) {
        $atts[ 'aria-label' ] = strip_tags( $item->title ) . ' Menu';
    }
    
    return $atts;
}
```

I'm not using the `$args` or `$depth` parameters, so I could leave them off, but having them in place means I know I can use them if I am reaching for this code another time.

Answer (score 1):

You must have a `title` attribute in `<a>` tag, you really wont require a `aria-label` attr then. All screen readers read the title of  tag automatically.

`aria-label` might have been required in case you didnt have the content as clean text but more of a HTML code.

when you click on any link, you must add attr `aria-selected="true"`

so the end result being:

```
<li id="id_name" class="class_names">
    <a href="http://linktothepage.com/page" title="TITLE OF MY PAGE">TITLE OF MY PAGE</a>
</li>
```

If the navigation menu item on page load is the *selected item* then:

```
<li id="id_name" class="class_names">
    <a href="http://linktothepage.com/page" title="TITLE OF MY PAGE" aria-selected="true">TITLE OF MY PAGE</a>
</li>
```

Comment: The [title attribute is not announced reliably](https://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2013/01/using-the-html-title-attribute-updated/) by assistive technology.